# Android 10 - Create an SQlite database under Documents folder

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-file, android-storage

With Android 10, I want to create an SQLite database in the Documents folder under a created folder 'MyFolder'.

I'm using the following code to create a folder (which seems to work):

```
  mActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
          new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {

              if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri treeUri = result.getData().getData();

                Log.d(TAG, "treeUri: " + treeUri);

                DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(mContext, treeUri);
                DocumentFile newDir = pickedDir.createDirectory("MyFolder");

                String path = newDir.getUri().getPath();

                Log.d(TAG, "Path: " + path);

              }
            }
          });

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
  mOpenFileTreeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

It returns:

```
/tree/home:/document/home:MyFolder
```

..for the created folder path.

I would normally use:

```
String myDatabasePath = path + "/MyDatabase.sqlite";
mDb = openOrCreateDatabase(myDatabasePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

..but I don't believe 'path' is a valid path.

When I test for existence of 'path' below, the folder cannot be found - but I can see it in Android Studio's Device File Explorer (under /storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyFolder)

```
File dir = new File(myDatabasePath);

if (dir.exists()) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Folder exists!");
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "Folder does not exist!");
}
```

Can I not use the actual path? Is there a way to get the proper path from the URI?

I'm trying to get my app to work on Android 10. My app was written 8 years ago and worked fine on earlier versions of Android prior to 10. I even managed to get it working on Android 11 - and with full path names but I am struggling with Android 10 in particular using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't want the user to pick their own save directory? You could simply follow my guide [here](https://gavingt.medium.com/refactoring-my-backup-and-restore-feature-to-comply-with-scoped-storage-e2b6c792c3b) if you're ok doing that.

Comment: @GavinWright I'm happy for the user to choose their own folder. My main concern is being able to create a SQlite database in that folder. If I can only get the URI, how do I create the database when the path returned is invalid? Or is it invalid?

Comment: "With Android 10, I want to create an SQLite database in the Documents folder under a created folder 'MyFolder'" -- that is not going to be practical. Use an ordinary directory that you have full read/write access to, such as those supplied by methods on `Context`. For example, you could store your database in its default location (`getDatabasePath()`), then offer backup/restore or import/export options to a user-specified location on external storage.

Comment: To elaborate on CommonsWare's post, we no longer have arbitrary `java.io.file` access everywhere on the user's phone. But part of Scoped Storage is that each app has its own internal folders that we're still allowed full access to. So we can write our .sqlite file in one of these folders, and then copy it to a destination chosen by the user (via the SAF picker). The copying part is where `Uri`s come in, as you basically need to pipe your internally stored `File`'s data over to the `Uri` returned by the SAF picker. This exact scenario is covered in detail in the link I posted above.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK. I think I can live with creating MyFolder under /data/user/0/com.blah/files/MyFolder for now. I've used getFilesDir().getPath() on Context.

Android 11 seems to allow me access to public folders such as Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS via getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() but I guess Android 10 didn't have that capability.

The big challenge is going to be when I want to access files from my external SD card - .mod, .sid files and the likes which the MediaStore is not going to recognise.

Comment: "The big challenge is going to be when I want to access files from my external SD card - .mod, .sid files and the likes which the MediaStore is not going to recognise" -- and for that, the SAF is the right answer. However, if you are using some third-party library for those formats, where that library needs filesystem access (versus simply reading/writing streams), you will need the same sort of approaches that we've outlined: use read/write locations primarily, with removable storage as a destination for import/export or backup/restore operations.

Comment: I'm still not sure how you have access to this directory in Android 11 but not in Android 10. Is it because of [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html)?

Comment: @GavinWright I don't have the code in front of me at the moment, but with Android 11 my app requests whether it can have file access - not sure if it's "manage all access" or something. One it gets that permission, it happily gets the DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS path and things are good.

Comment: @SparkyNZ All Files access isn't something I would rely upon. It's a special permission that you have to apply for before you can use it on the Play Store. And Google prefers to grant this permission only to apps that require it (like File Manager apps).

Comment: @CommonsWare the good news is that I wrote all the NDK code for playing those .mod files. I don't really want to port all of my C/C++ code into Java so I hope it will play along nicely. Even if I have to copy a file in Java first to a location that the NDK code can access, then that will be fine. I'm pretty sure SAF will allow enumeration of files (listFiles() ? API) once the user selects the device and folder. Hope so. :-)

Comment: @GavinWright this is only my personal app now - its a music player for my phone and car stereos. I gave up trying to support it on GooglePlay - my daytime job was enough :-)

Comment: @SparkyNZ: "I'm pretty sure SAF will allow enumeration of files (listFiles() ? API) once the user selects the device and folder" -- you will want to use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to wrap around the `Uri` you get back from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! This worked! I thought the URI for the USB drive changed every app launch, reboot, removal etc but it appears to be consistent and I can access the root tree using the URI directly upon reboot too.

Comment: Yes, if you use `takePersistableUriPermission()`, you can have durable access to that document tree. If the user does something dramatic, like delete the tree, then you lose access.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm glad you mentioned that because I just rebooted and I don't seem to have access to the individual file URIs without going through ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE again. I'll search takePersistableUriPermission() to figure it out. I am building up my own MP3 database of URI paths - and trying to play one of those MP3 using it URI but it doesn't work after reboot

Comment: @CommonsWare that also did the trick! There's some good info about takePersistableUriPermission() here too: https://andreamaglie.com/software-development/access-storage-framework-and-the-uri-permissions-nightmare/ Thanks again! I might be able to get this car stereo into my car after all of these months!

Answer (score 0):

> > String path = newDir.getUri().getPath();

That path is only for internal use of the provider. Your app should use the uri.

The complete content scheme which you can see with `String contentscheme = newDir.getUri().toString();`

And you cannot use content schemes for the `File` class.

> > trying to get my app to work on Android 10.

Just add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to application tag in manifest file and you are done using the old code.